2D assets loading before loading.tsx, then loading.tsx only shows while loading 3D assets in NextJS
I am facing an unexpected bug. On my page I have a bunch of 2D images and assets and one 3D model. When I open the website, the 2D assets show, then the loading.tsx file shows and then disappears when the 3D asset loads.
I tried using loading.tsx files in NextJS. I also tried using Suspense and fallback. I can use state as a last resort but that would turn my nextjs project into react

Can you explain in more detail about your issue? This explanation doesn't cut it. In fact with this explanation I feel everything is working fine xD.
For example, what is your expected output?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
